# I have a Golang audio function, recordAudio, doing both capture and playback. How can I split it into two functions?

Tags: go, audio

I'm working on an audio recording and playback application in Golang using fyne and the "malgo" library. In my code, I've encountered issues with two variables, `sizeInBytes` and `pCapturedSamples`, and I'm not sure where to declare and initialize them correctly.

```
func recordAudio() {
    ctx, deviceConfig, err := initializeAudio()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer func() {
        _ = ctx.Uninit()
        ctx.Free()
    }()
    sizeInBytes := uint32(malgo.SampleSizeInBytes(deviceConfig.Capture.Format))
    pCapturedSamples := make([]byte, 0)

    onRecvFrames := func(pSample2, pSample []byte, framecount uint32) {

        sampleCount := framecount * deviceConfig.Capture.Channels * sizeInBytes

        newCapturedSampleCount := capturedSampleCount + sampleCount

        pCapturedSamples = append(pCapturedSamples, pSample...)

        capturedSampleCount = newCapturedSampleCount

    }

    fmt.Println("Recording...")
    captureCallbacks := malgo.DeviceCallbacks{
        Data: onRecvFrames,
    }
    device, err := malgo.InitDevice(ctx.Context, deviceConfig, captureCallbacks)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = device.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Press Enter to stop recording...")
    fmt.Scanln()

    device.Uninit()

    onSendFrames := func(pSample, nil []byte, framecount uint32) {
        samplesToRead := framecount * deviceConfig.Playback.Channels * sizeInBytes
        if samplesToRead > capturedSampleCount-playbackSampleCount {
            samplesToRead = capturedSampleCount - playbackSampleCount
        }

        copy(pSample, pCapturedSamples[playbackSampleCount:playbackSampleCount+samplesToRead])

        playbackSampleCount += samplesToRead

        if playbackSampleCount == uint32(len(pCapturedSamples)) {
            playbackSampleCount = 0
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Playing...")
    playbackCallbacks := malgo.DeviceCallbacks{
        Data: onSendFrames,
    }

    device, err = malgo.InitDevice(ctx.Context, deviceConfig, playbackCallbacks)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = device.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Press Enter to quit...")
    fmt.Scanln()

    device.Uninit()
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: What are the issues you encountered?

Comment: @soundflix i have an error panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:2204] with capacity 0

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main.playbackAudio.func2({0x7f26b0016620?, 0xc000000002?, 0x7f26b0008300?}, {0x7f269c026ab0?, 0x89c?, 0x0?}, 0x0?)
        /home/pablo/nutriguia/main.go:136 +0xcd
github.com/gen2brain/malgo.goDataCallback(0x7f26b0008300, 0x7f26b0016620, 0x7f26b0015d70, 0x44e)
        /home/pablo/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/malgo@v0.11.10/device.go:175 +0x1c9
exit status 2